# Using a URL with square brackets in MatLab

Tags: matlab, url, restful-url

I am using webread to download data from a RESTful web service. The URL is constructed as:

'http://someurl/service.php?query=data&options'

one of the options is '&includesensors[]=XXX' where XXX is a sensor type. This option fails because MatLab converts the square brackets to '&includesensors%5B%5D=XXX'

Any idea on how to get MatLab to pass this option without messing with it?

Comment: Can you clarify, is '&includesensors[]=XXX' something you input or something else?

Comment: If you don't find a better option, I guess you could always just post-process it with string replacement: [`strrep('&includesensors%5B%5D=XXX' ,'%5B','[')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html)

Comment: @milez It's appended to the URL as an option using '&'.

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure how would that work. I need to pass the URL to webread. How do I 'post-process' it before passing it to the function?

Comment: @Carlos I thought you were getting it back from webread... never mind then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was to build the url and then passing it on to webread, like:

```
url = 'http://someurl/service.php?query=data&includesensors[]=XXX'
data = webread(url);
```

which results in the options (including the '[]') being passed to urlencode (I'm guessing)

but the proper way to do this is:

```
url = 'http://someurl/service.php';
data = webread(url,'query','data','includesensors','XXX');
```

which works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing your brackets in braces: `{[}`.

Matlab uses LaTeX formatting. In this case square brackets have a specific meaning so you will have to escape them with braces.